# task_set_bootstrap_port in parent causes child to hang

Tags: objective-c, macos, osx-lion

The behavior of `task_set_bootstrap_port` has changed between OS X 10.6 and 10.7. In 10.6, this worked:

```
// parent process
mach_port_t parent_recv_port = MACH_PORT_NULL;
setup_recv_port (&parent_recv_port);
task_set_bootstrap_port(mach_task_self(), parent_recv_port); 
NSTask *qtTask = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[qtTask setLaunchPath:...]; 
[qtTask launch];
...
```

---

```
// child process
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    mach_port_t parent_recv_port = MACH_PORT_NULL; 
    task_get_bootstrap_port(mach_task_self(), &parent_recv_port); 
    ...
}
```

In 10.7, however, the child process does not execute the first line of `main` immediately after the parent calls `-launch` -- it waits until the parent process terminates. (Though the child process does immediately show up in `ps`.)

I've narrowed the problem down to the call to `task_set_bootstrap_port`. When the call is absent, the child process does not hang. And, if I restore the bootstrap port to the original immediately after `task_set_bootstrap_port`--

```
task_set_bootstrap_port(mach_task_self(), bootstrap_port);
```

-- then the child process also does not hang.

Error handling code has been omitted from above, but in reality it's checking for errors after every call. No errors.

So, any idea why the behavior of `task_set_bootstrap_port` has changed from 10.6 to 10.7? And is there a workaround?

Constraints:

- Need access to a `mach_port_t` to pass to `IOSurfaceLookupFromMachPort`.
- Runloop may not exist, so can't use `NSMachPort` or `CFMachPort`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple Developer Technical Support tells me that temporarily changing the bootstrap port, as this code was doing, was never guaranteed to work. In this case XPC was trying to message the boostrap port after it had been changed, and that was failing so things broke.

A quick fix is to use `bootstrap_register` (though deprecated) in the parent process and `bootstrap_look_up` in the child. This lets the child look up the parent by name (a string) and get a port from it.